# How do I set up tunneling in MobaXterm similar to my current PuTTY setup?

Tags: ssh, unix, putty, ssh-tunnel, mobaxterm

Here's what I do with PuTTY:

```
PuTTY settings, Connection > SSH > Tunnels:
source = 8000
destination = 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And then after I ssh into ServerA (a unix jump server in this instance), I use the following command to log into ServerB:

```
$ ssh serverB -L 8000:0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then I run the source command for the Django virtual environment, then the following runserver command:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And then I am able to access the website on my local machine via http://127.0.0.1:8000.

How do I set up this kind of thing in MobaXterm? I can't figure it out; its Tunneling options are much more confusing, and everything I try fails to work.

Comment: Is `0.0.0.0` used as an example here, or is it the literal address that you've used in PuTTY's configuration?

Comment: That is the literal address. My PuTTY setup works perfectly fine. I'm just wondering how it is done in MobaXterm. The only examples are ServerA and ServerB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MobaXterm, open the MobaSSHtunnel and select "Local port forwarding"

Enter the following information:

**Forwarded port** - the port on your browser that you will use to access the Django site on your local machine (example: 1234 so that you can access the website on localhost:1234)

**SSH server** - the IP address of your remote server

**SSH login** - your username on the remote server

**SSH port** - the port on the SSH server that you use (usually 22).

**Remote server** - the address of the Django site on the remote server (`127.0.0.1` on your case)

**Remote port** - the port of the Django site on the remote server (`8000` on your case)

In this example, I access the Django site on `localhost:1234` on my browser:
[image: in the image in this example, I access the Django site on localhost:1234 on my browser]

If you use an SSH key for logging in, you can add a key after you have saved the tunnel.

To add SSH key, press the key on the "Settings":
[image: to add SSH key, press the key on the "settings"]

Afterward, you can open the Django app on your own browser at `localhost:1234`! :)

Comment: or for simplicity, you can use this command on you mobaxterm when running the manage.py instead: "$python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" then you can access it on the ip of your remote server, at port 8000. No need for port forwarding